# Json.jbuilder merge 2 json data and send it to one key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5 and i am using jbuilder for sending json. The problem i am facing is i want to merge 2 table json and send it to same key..

my json.jbuilder look like this

```
json.children env.sites do |site|
  json.nodeId "site_#{site.id}"
  json.type "site"
  json.extract! site,:id, :key, :name
  json.children site.networks do |network|
    json.nodeId "network_#{network.id}"
    json.type "network"
    json.extract! network,:id, :name
    json.children network.vlans do |vlan|
      json.type "vlan"
      json.extract! vlan,:id, :name
    end
  end
  json.children site.instances do |instance|
    json.type "host"
    json.extract! instance,:id, :name
    json.content do
      json.cpu instance.cpu
    end
  end
end
```

Issue i am facing over here is i want to merge site.networks and site.instaces in same key.. How i would achieve this..??

Comment: same key as in? what is the current and expected json output?

Comment: Current output is override the children key with site.instances data and expected is it should merge site.networks and site.instances json

Comment: it doesn't help much. You just can't merge anything..many of your keys are same, can you post expected json output? what needs to be array and what needs to be hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json.array!`

Try this,

```
json.children env.sites do |site|
  json.nodeId "site_#{site.id}"
  json.type "site"
  json.extract! site,:id, :key, :name
  json.children do
    json.array!(site.networks) do |network|
      json.nodeId "network_#{network.id}"
      json.type "network"
      json.extract! network,:id, :name
      json.children network.vlans do |vlan|
        json.type "vlan"
        json.extract! vlan,:id, :name
      end
    end
    json.array!(site.instances) do |instance|
      json.type "host"
      json.extract! instance,:id, :name
      json.content do
        json.cpu instance.cpu
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The solution works but in my case, an additional requirement is for caching. Can I cache the 'site.networks' array in the above case as,      # json.cache_collection! site.networks, key: 'site_network_array' do |network|  ........  end